# How to save action output in a variable or RDD in python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and implementing it using python.I have a problem set in which i need to store the first line of the file in a RDD and then do more transformations on it. So i am trying to do it using first() action.But using first() action , it just show me the output on the screen but not able to store it in another variable or RDD. Is there a way in python to store the output of action in a variable or RDD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first() should be executed on RDD (not on the file)

Assuming that you have an RDD to start with - both "first()" and "take(1)" should work....

```
myvar1 = myRDD.take(1)
myvar2 = myRDD.first()
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html

**take(num)**

Take the first num elements of the RDD.

It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit.

Note that this method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s memory.

```
>>> sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).cache().take(2)
[2, 3]
>>> sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).take(10)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**first()**

Return the first element in this RDD.

```
>>> sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4]).first()
2
```